# Rails environment how to find out in code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

are there any solutions how I can find out in which environment my application is running?

I have some rake calls wich need to have the environment like this:

```
system "RAILS_ENV=development rake crons:dosomething"
```

But this should not only work in development I want to use this in test production and development?

how can I do this?

second task where I need this is in config/schedule.rb the should also run in all environments

```
rake "crons:dosomething", :environment => :development
rake "crons:dosomething", :environment => :production
```

this dosn't work

Comment: You need to call [`Rails.env`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Rails/env/class) to get the current environment name.. and [`env=`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Rails/env%3D/class) to set the environment.

Comment: are you trying to run this code from console? or from you application?

Comment: code is running from application, first snipped is running on button click and second snipped is called from whenever as cronjob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do

```
Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.development?
```

with any of the environments you have.

Alternatively to pass an environment to a rake task you can do this

`rake "crons:dosomething RAILS_ENV=production"`

Comment: Rails.env works in controller thats fine, but in the schedule.rb it dosn't work. Can't use there the Rails.env ... Because this file is set the crontab file whith whenever -w

Answer (score 1):

You can match it to strings like:

```
if Rails.env.eql?('production')
  #Do production things
end
```